# How do I communicate multiple ARINC429 channels with SPI slave device in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, spi, vlsi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40He8.jpg)

I am developing an application of receiving Master data from CPU and transmiting to multiple channels through the SPI salve.
How do I do memory map for SPI slaves for multiple channels
How do I communicate multiple ARINC429 channels with SPI slave device in VHDL

Answer (score 0):

> How do I do memory map for SPI slaves for multiple channels

It looks like you want an SPI slave which routes data to other SPI masters. For that you have to make up your own protocol. e.g. a start byte which is the destination address followed by to original data. You have to implement that at the master side in the driver software and alongside your SPI slave code in the HDL language.

> How do I communicate multiple ARINC429 channels with SPI slave device in VHDL.

I had to look up what "ARINC429" was. What I found is that it is *"..the physical and electrical interfaces of a two-wire data bus and a data protocol to support an aircraft's avionics local area network."*

My fist reaction was ***Don't touch!*** I have not worked in avionics but what I understand is that they are very strict on safety. Even with my many years experience in HDL design I would be reluctant to build a circuit unless under guidance of a safety expert.

If you still want to go ahead: you have to read up on the ARINC429 protocol and make a *ARINC429 to SPI master protocol* converter. As I said: I have no knowledge of ARINC429 but if the protocol is complex you might need a micro controller alongside the HDL code.

Comment: Thanks for information Oldfart.
Here SPI slave which doesn't routes data to other SPI masters.
But SPI slave which routes data to ARINC channels.
For this I needs SPI slave in VHDL which receives the data from SPI master and routes to the different ARINC429 channels based on the channel configurations